# jQuery find and insert (jQuery replace)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```
<div class="twtr-tweet-text">
    <p>lorem ipsum <em>date 19th nov</em></p>
</div>
<div class="twtr-tweet-text">
    <p>lorem ipsum <em>date 18th nov</em></p>
</div>
<div class="twtr-tweet-text">
    <p>lorem ipsum <em>date 17th nov</em></p>
</div>
```

How can I transform this block to the code below. Keeping in mind that multiple blocks contain the same class names etc.

```
<div class="twtr-tweet-text">
    <p><img src="speech_left.jpg" />lorem ipsum <img src="speech_right.jpg" /><em>date 19th nov</em></p>
</div>
```

So before the `<em>` starting tag and right after the `<p>` tag after the `.twtr-tweet-text{}` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, in addition to [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214180/jquery-find-and-insert-jquery-replace/8214203#8214203):

```
$('<img src="speech_left.jpg" />').prependTo($('.twtr-tweet-text p'));
```

---

**Edited** to add a plain-JavaScript means of achieving the same:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    leftImageSrc = 'speech_left.jpg',
    rightImageSrc = 'speech_right.jpg',
    className = 'twtr-tweet-text',
    parent, // used in the loop, below
    img; // used in the loop, below

for (i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    parent = elems[i].parentNode; // looking at two qualities of the parent,
                                  // so storing it in a variable
    if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div' && parent.className == className){
    // the 'if' tests that the parent is a div, and
    // that the parent has a class-name of 'twtr-tweet-text'
        // left image:
        lImg = document.createElement('img');
        lImg.src = leftImageSrc;
        // the firstChild of the elems[i] element is the textNode
        elems[i].insertBefore(lImg,elems[i].firstChild);

        // right image:
        rImg = document.createElement('img');
        rImg.src = rightImageSrc;
        elems[i].appendChild(rImg);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/STtVc/3/).

Comment: How could I do Scott Brown and your answer in NORMAL javaScript?

Comment: See the edited/updated answer. I'm not sure about IE (unavailable for testing), but it works in Chromium 14 and Firefox 7.

Comment: ...and this is why I use jQuery :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.twtr-tweet-text p').prepend('<img src="speech_left.jpg" />');
$('.twtr-tweet-text em').before('<img src="speech_right.jpg" />');
```

Comment: It won't work, and it does not bring errors, so my CSS call is not working. I though jQuery can do CSS jumps, edit code.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.twtr-tweet-text p').prepend('<img src="/blog/assets/imgs/speech-mark-left.jpg" />');
 $('.twtr-tweet-text p em').before('<img src="/blog/assets/imgs/speech-mark-right.jpg" />');
});

Comment: How could I do this in NORMAL javaScript?